# Unable to Mock RestTemplate.exchange class..getting RestTemplate not application for arguments error

Tags: junit, mockito

I am trying to mock the restTeamplate.exchange method but I am getting the below error when trying to mock
The method exchange(String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity, Class, Object...) in the type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity, Object)

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(
            Matchers.anyString(),
            Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), 
            Matchers.<Object> any())
        ).thenReturn(myResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it but replacing the 
    `Matchers.<Object> any()`
with 
    `Matchers.<Class<responseClassName>> any()`.